# Read an .xls file in Linux Machine without having MS Office Installed

Tags: java, excel, linux, selenium, apache-poi

I have a Linux machine with open office installed. **I don't have MS Office installed in my Linux machine.**
 I have imported an Excel file with (.xls) extension in my Linux machine.
I want to read data from that file. I have a java code with APACHE POI library to read excel (which worked fine in my windows machine).

Can i use same APACHE POI library to read this Excel file in Linux Machine without having MS Office installed?

Comment: Yes, you can use Apache POI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your java code and apache poi library in all the operating systems where jvm is supported without having Microsoft office, Open Office or any other Office software installed.